# How can I write equations using LaTex in a Trello card?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, latex

I'm using Trello to organize my research and find it difficult to write cards without equations in them. I feel that it also defeats the purpose to add pdf files to every card. Is there any way to embed LaTex lines into a card?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The description supports [markdown and embedded images](https://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello). I use a service from [codecogs.com](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) to write equations online and where it says "click here to download" copy the link and put that into the Trello description.

For a simple equation my description in Trello would look something like:

`![a=\frac{b}{c}](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?a%3D%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%7D)`

Comment: It looks like the page has changed since you submitted your answer. You have to click `Export` and then can select the format, whether HTML, URL, etc. to generate the output you want. IMO this is an enhancement that makes it even better but wanted to flag for others coming to this answer later like me.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a browser extension like Tampermonkey, you can run a script whenever you open a Trello page which will load MathJax. Then you can write LaTeX math like normal and it will be rendered nicely for you. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/neighthan/756fbb4ce6ccc40b77cc4eeb13379fe4) my script for this.

Comment: IMHO, this answer is more elegant than the accepted one.